# Pyomo Optimization Varible to be set as multiple of some value

Tags: mathematical-optimization, pyomo

S=B^b

log(S)=b*log(B)  #This is the Objective function#

S=Sales Share i.e "Sales of Category/Sales of dept"

b=Space bay Share i.e "Space bay of Category/Space Bay of dept"

```
model.objective = pyomo.Objective(rule= sum( exp(log( model.space[c] /  model.sapce_sum[c] )  *    model.sales_coeff[c][0]  +   model.sales_intercept[c]
                 )  *      model.sales_sum[c] for c in   model.dept_cat_nbr   ), sense=pyomo.maximize)
```

The regression model is formed and coefficients are stored that would be used for Sales forecasting.
Depending on the space_bay the Sales would be calculated multiplying with the coefficients.

space[c]=categry level space_bay

model.space_sum[c]=dept lebel space bay

( model.space[c] /  model.sapce_sum[c]  )=space bay share to use the coeffieints calculated and stored earlier

model.dept_cat_nbr is a set like '90_1400','95_1200','06_4000','92_1100' etc.

model.space_bay is the variable to be optimized that would define space to be allocated for the dept_cat above to optimize demand.

model.multiple is a parm set as say 0.5, 1,1,0.5 etc that I have created to control that whether the above dept_catg to be solved can occupy half self or full self which is pre-defined.

So my expectation is model.space_bay  for '90_1400' being half self catrgory,the o/p would return either in 2.5 or 3 i.e half self or full self not 2.7

Similarly '95_1200' is a full self occupied category so the o/p model.space_bay would rertun in 3 or 4 not even 3.5 or 4.7 etc.

In order to acheive that I declared a integer variable model.space_bay_integer
and depending on the dept_catrgory restriction half/full self, I defined model.multiple.

But as I have to use the non-linear optimizer like 'ipopt' that treats the model.space_bay_integer as continuous values. Hence does not come in whole number.

Probably my solution would work if I use some linear optimizer like glpk or cplex. But as my objective fuction as log and exp terms I won't be able to use the linear optimizer solvers.
Please let me know in case you need any more information.

*Update(04/25) ends:*

I am working on a optimization problem using Pyomo.

**Objective**
The target variable that needs to be optimised should be multiple of 0.5 or 1.

Example:
model.space_bay which is my target variable should be like 0.5 ,1,10,15.5 etc which is multiple of 0.5 or 1 depending on what is set through the index.

**Approach 1:**
I first tried to implement kind of below using a constraint.

```
def abide_space_multiples(model,i):
    return  model.space_bay[i]% model.multiple[i]==0
model.space_multiple_cons = pyomo.Constraint(model.dept_cat_nbr,rule = abide_space_multiples)
```

where model.dept_cat_nbr is indexed and defines what would be the multiple like 0.5 or 1. Example of model.multiple[i] is as follows.
{'95_1200': 0.5,
'95_4200': 0.5,
'95_3305': 0.5,
'95_2210': 0.5}

**Conclusion**
Failed because Pyomo does not support % operator

**Approach 2:**
I have defined one variable  space_bay_integer with integer domain and second variable(target variable) space_bay to be 0.5 or 1 multiple of the first variable depending on the variable index multiple values(0.5 or 1). It is enforced through pyomo constraint space_multiple_cons.

```
#Define Bays only in integer terms
model.space_bay_integer=pyomo.Var(model.dept_cat_nbr, domain=pyomo.Integers)

## Second Variable(Target Variable)
#Lower and Upper Bound
model.bay_lb=pyomo.Param(model.dept_cat_nbr, initialize={df_sum_wt.loc[i,'dept_catg']: df_sum_wt.loc[i,'min_bay'] for i in range(len(df_sum_wt))})
model.bay_ub=pyomo.Param(model.dept_cat_nbr, initialize={df_sum_wt.loc[i,'dept_catg']: df_sum_wt.loc[i,'max_bay'] for i in range(len(df_sum_wt))})

model.space_bay = pyomo.Var(model.dept_cat_nbr, domain = pyomo.NonNegativeReals, bounds = {i: (model.bay_lb[i],model.bay_ub[i]) for i in model.dept_cat_nbr})

# create space constraint 
def abide_space_multiples(model,i):
    return  model.space_bay[i]==model.space_bay_integer[i]*model.multiple[i]
model.space_multiple_cons = pyomo.Constraint(model.dept_cat_nbr,rule = abide_space_multiples)
```

**Conclusion**:**
In output to my surprise  space_bay_integer does not return in  full integer as defined in domain. Rather returns in fraction.
'92_1802': 4.409958751988682,
'92_2300': 20.000000199999704,
'90_1103': 20.000000199612032,
'13_1100': 2.5488727024046463,

Also the space_bay though multiple is maintained all is 0.5 times of space_bay_integer  but as space_bay_integer is not maintaining the restriction of integer domain,the space_bay is coming as non-multiple of 0.5
'92_1802': 2.20497937599434
'92_2300':10.0000000999998
'90_1103': 10.000000099806
'13_1100':1.27443635120232

Comment: Little confusing....  of course 1 is a multiple of 0.5, so are you trying to say that in some cases you'd allow 0.5 increments and others not, and this is not known in advance and that decision is also a model variable?  Your current solution now multiplies two (assumed) variables, making it non-linear, which is *probably* not what you want to do.  It would be extremely helpful (to you) if you could describe the interplay between the 0.5 / 1 multiples and produce a small example with toy data that is fully defined, even if it doesn't work completely.

Comment: What is the solving status of your model? It may be infeasible and throwing a solution at you anyway, this is why you must check if the solution is optimal, feasible or infeasible. And like @AirSquid seems to mention, you might have a non-linear problem. Linear solvers typically really hate non-linearity. What is the solving status of your solution? See https://pyomo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/working_models.html#accessing-solver-status if it can guide you. Please, come back with the solution/solver status.

Comment: Oh, also, keep in mind that a solver has a numeric precision that may not be the same precision as the one used by Python. 10.0000000999998 shouldn't be worrying, just round it at the required decimal place. Depending on the solver, this can be set, but you may encounter performance or solution issues doing so. So I recommend rounding to a significant number of digit, ex: 10.0000 sould be a good rounding, precise enough to let you know of a significant fractional number, but not enough to collect all the noise from the numeric precision.

Comment: @AirSquid Thanks for your response.  The variable space_bay is Indexed through something named dept_cat_nbr set.
Some of dept_cat_nbr should be multiple of 0.5
Rest of dept_cat_nbr should be whole number.
This criteria is predefined and I have stored the same in model.multiple[i].

In order to achieve that I have declared space_bay_integer variable as integer and indexed multiple should have taken care whether that should be multiple of 0.5 or 1(whole number).

model.space_bay[i]==model.space_bay_integer[i]*model.multiple[i]

Comment: @V.Brunelle Thanks to you as well for your response.
Yes the optimizer IPOPT which is being used is a non linear optimizer. Hence the space_bay_integer that I expected to be integer is actually returning in fraction even not close to integer value.
Hence multiple of 0.5 or 1 as defined through model.multiple[i] does not provide the desired effect on model.space_bay[i]

Comment: @V.Brunelle Also the solving status is as follows.   "this is feasible and optimal"

Comment: @V.Brunelle The issue is the variables defined as integers are given values like '95_2502': 3.4629263628592732,  '13_1001': 2.7448818202619, '92_2000': 7.513948039074737, along with some good numbers like '97_1002': 4.000000039788348,  '02_2000': 0.9999999813936026, that we can round off. I guess because ipopt optimizer converts integer to continuous.

Comment: I can almost guarantee there is a completely better way to do this....  But I'm having trouble understanding what you mean by a variable being "controlled" by the index.  Can you edit your post and give a concrete example of what you are talking about by maybe showing a possible set of values for `space_bay` and how it relates to the other index.

Comment: Thanks @AirSquid for looking into this. As per your requested I have tried to provide some better explanation to the problem.

Comment: It is a bit more clear now.  I'd look for a substitute objective function that is linear...  do you really need exponents and logs?  Can you post your obj function (or some reasonable facsimile of it) and an explanation of what the objective is?

Comment: Hi @AirSquid Please find the above the simplified version of objective function.